# how to calculate sum of dynamically named model names in a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, lodash, linq.js

I have a dynamic table with dynamic inputs. Each input has an unique number added to the end of the model name. There are 10 inputs per table with the last being the total. I need to watch the first 9 inputs and calculate the sum. Here is what the json looks like after dynamically assigning unique model names.

```
[
 {
"section_id": 3155,
"subdivision_id": 3500,
"section_name": "Ph 1(P)-Mercedes",
"sectionInputs": [
  {
    "model": "price_min-3155"
  },
  {
    "model": "price_max-3155"
  },
  {
    "model": "units_occ-3155"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_mod-3155"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_fin-3155"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_vdl-3155"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_uc-3155"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_fut-3155"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_con-3155"
  },
  {
    "model": "units_total-3155"
     }
  ]
},
{
"section_id": 12863,
"subdivision_id": 3500,
"section_name": "Ph 1(P)-Adams",
"sectionInputs": [
  {
    "model": "price_min-12863"
  },
  {
    "model": "price_max-12863"
  },
  {
    "model": "units_occ-12863"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_mod-12863"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_fin-12863"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_vdl-12863"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_uc-12863"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_fut-12863"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_con-12863"
  },
  {
    "model": "units_total-12863"
  }
]
},
{
"section_id": 16152,
"subdivision_id": 3500,
"section_name": "Ph 1(P)-Unassigned",
"sectionInputs": [
  {
    "model": "price_min-16152"
  },
  {
    "model": "price_max-16152"
  },
  {
    "model": "units_occ-16152"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_mod-16152"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_fin-16152"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_vdl-16152"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_uc-16152"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_fut-16152"
  },
  {
    "model": "inv_con-16152"
  },
  {
    "model": "units_total-16152"
  }
  ]
 }
]
```

The `units_total` needs to hold the sum value for each array.  I was looking at using a watchgroup function but not sure how I could do this with possibly needing a for loop? I'm open to suggestions on the best way to handle this. **javascript**, **jquery**, **lodash**, **linq.js** are what is currently being used in project.

Here is
[working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FecyxWKeFXaI5C8jhAfh?p=preview)

```
 $scope.model = {};

   function prepareDataForView() {
    for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
        sections[i].sectionInputs = sectionInputSvc.sectionInputs(sections[i]);
        sections[i].sectionInputLabels = sectionInputLabels;
    }

    $scope.sections = sections;
}
prepareDataForView();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to implement this is to calculate the total whenever input `ng-change`s:

```
var sum = function(acc,cur){ return acc+cur; }
$scope.modelChanged = function(section, input){
  var inputsCount = section.sectionInputs.length;
  var totalInput = section.sectionInputs[inputsCount-1];
  if(input === totalInput){
    return;
  }
  var total = section.sectionInputs.slice(0, inputsCount - 1).map(function(input){
    return $scope.model[input.model];
  }).filter(angular.isDefined).reduce(sum, 0);

  $scope.model[totalInput.model] = total;
};
```

Which can then be invoked on each input:

```
<input ng-model="model[input.model]"  ng-change="modelChanged(section, input)" type="number" />
```

Here's [an updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2ASc5EX8wxMxXYy8fp3e?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have solved it with jQuery, maybe this answer doesn't fit you because it's inconsistent with your angular app, but I hope it can be helpful to someone else.

```
$(document).on("change", "input", function()
{
    $tr = $(this).parent().parent();
    $tds = $tr.find("td");
    var sum = 0;
    $.each($tds, function(index, td){
        var valueInput = $(td).find("input").val();
        if(index < 9 ){
            sum += parseFloat((valueInput != "") ? valueInput : 0 );
        }
    });

    $tds.eq(9).find("input").val(sum);
});
```

Here is the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/88WigW1zsU3BLkZi8non?p=preview)

Comment: how about taking a look at my next question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735027/how-to-bind-data-from-dynamically-named-inputs-inside-a-ng-repeat

Comment: Hi, I have added a new answer/solution to that question, ;) If you'd like to check it out.

Comment: awesome! ill take a look. and i actually am going to have another for you in a bit!