# how to bind data from dynamically named inputs inside a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, lodash, linq.js

my goal is to be able to copy data from a table row to another table row.
[image: table rows]

if the data from 2015 has not changed from 2016 the user needs a quick way of copying the values into the 2016 input fields. the models are dynamically created for these forms. the data you see in this image is assigned to a section. the input models are name 'price_min + section_id', price_max + section_id' , etc...
the history model does not have the section_id added to the end of the model names. so there needs to be a mapping function that i need help with. I need to map the history values to the current model convention and update the view with the values.

currently i have a click function that brings in the matched section history. here is a screen shot of what that looks like.

[image: history model]

in that same function i have the 2016 object array with the current model naming convention.

[image: new model names]

i need to copy the history values into the inputArray. how i go about doing this, i dont know? I have complete control on how this works. and in the plunker you will see how i did this. if i need to change something else to make this work then that is ok. javascript, jquery, lodash, linq.js is currently being used in project.

working plunker
[working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HYmYPXZC4UwQ3vPgFmNa?p=preview)

```
$scope.copyHistoryData = function (section) {
    var selected = Enumerable.From(sectionsHistory).Where("x => x.section_id == '" + section.section_id + "'").ToArray();
    selected = selected[0];
    var inputArry = section.sectionInputs;
};
```

Comment: if its not too much, could you make a .git repo for this?

Comment: here's a tutorial, https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/ but i think it'll be too much effort.

 anyways, to clarify, you want values from the first row to be copied into the second row?

Comment: yes, correct. thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you use such complex data structure, but here is my take on it

```
$scope.copyHistoryData = function (section, input) {
        var historyId=input.model.split('-')[0];
        var historyVal=section.sectionHistory[section.sectionHistory.length-1][historyId];
        $scope.model[input.model]=historyVal;
    };
```

To fill all fields:

```
$scope.copyHistoryData = function (section) {
      angular.forEach(section.sectionHistory[section.sectionHistory.length-1], function (historyVal, historyId) {
        var inputModel=historyId+"-"+section.section_id;
        $scope.model[inputModel]=historyVal;
      });
    };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/OOEmgzKB1pqKjSJMayVF?p=preview

Comment: im up for suggestions.

Comment: well does that function do what you want?

Comment: any chance i can copy the entire row at once. i just put the ng-click with every td because it was fast

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @ssh. The data structure is a mess. I think this is a better representation of what it should look like. Probably not the best but you shouldn't have to iterate through the data to then display it like that.

http://plnkr.co/C9DWV1dSvkk8lcYdm0An?p=preview

```
<div class="hpanel" ng-repeat="section in sections">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li>
              <h5>
                <b>SecID</b>
              </h5>
              <span>{{section.section_id}}</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h5>
                <b>Section Name</b>
              </h5>
              <span>{{section.section_name}}</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <hr/>
          <button ng-click="section.new_section_history = section.section_history">copy row</button>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td ng-repeat="label in labelIndex">
                {{label.label}}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td ng-repeat="label in labelIndex">
                {{section.section_history[label.index]}}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td ng-repeat="label in labelIndex">
                <input ng-model="section.new_section_history[label.index]"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td ng-repeat="label in labelIndex">
                <button ng-click="section.new_section_history[label.index] = section.section_history[label.index]">copy</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm always looking for simpler and better way to do things

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code, and I agree with @Steven Kaspar, the anchors in every row doesn't make much sense. I have solved it using jQuery (I know it doesn't follow your scheme with Angular, but it's another solution). 
I have added a new `<tr>` to add a `button` inside it.

Check this out:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="10"><button class="copyRow">Copy complete row</button></td>
</tr>
```

And in the `app.js`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".copyRow", function(){
    var $btn = $(this),
    $tbody = $btn.parent().parent().parent(),
    $trs = $tbody.find("tr");

    $.each($trs.eq(0).find("td"), function(index, td){
     $trs.eq(1).find("td").eq(index).find("input").val(parseFloat($(td).text().replace("$", "")));
    });
})
```

Here is the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uZYEQfPB5h1BztbUYlkX?p=preview). I hope it helps